# Collecting exported resources by shell script in java

Tags: java, shell, sh

I have a shell script named ***parameter.sh*** which is exporting few values like below,

```
export application="basic_html_test"
export directory=/dex2/grand/1
export path=$directory/application
```

I'm running this shell script from java using below code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"parameter.sh"});
```

My question is, Now I have to collect the data exported by ***parameter.sh***.
 i.e, `export application="basic_html_test"`. I want to collect the value of `application`. How do I do it? Please help. I tried searching for similar thing but didn't find answer exactly for my question.

Comment: AFAIK you wont get that. You would need to write them into a file and read that file.

Comment: If your script is runnable at all (only if it has a 'shebang' aka 'kerbang' line at the beginning) it is run in a new process, sets those envvars in the new process, and then the new process exits and everything in it is destroyed. If you run (but don't source) your script from a shell, that shell also can't 'collect' those exports. You don't actually need to write to a _file_ though; `Runtime.exec` captures, via a pipe, and thus can read anything the child process writes to its standard output.